# Git commit sha mismatches between developer machines

Tags: git

My coworker and I are working on a relatively large project with 20+ developers. We just discovered that we have a lot of mismatching commits on `origin/master`.

The content seems to be identical, but we can track commits going back to many years before we even started working on the project where the commit checksums are different.

What can be the cause of this and is there anything to be concerned about?

Comment: that sounds to me like you are not _really_ looking at the same thing.

Comment: Can you show us in the question what you mean with a mismatched commit id?

Comment: Is `git remote -v` showing the same for `origin` in both machines?

Comment: Yes, except the protocol (git versus https).

Answer (score 1):

I share the point of view of @eftshift0 that, in all likelihood, you are not looking at the same things.

To ensure it is the case, both of you should fetch the last version of `origin/master` and compare the last hash (i.e. tip of the `origin/master` remote branch). **If the hashes are equal, you could be sure that all the history is the same and that there is nothing wrong, you are not looking at the same thing.**

Some explanation...

Because the hash of a commit is calculated on the commit blob that contains the hash of parent commit(s). And that until the first commit. So, the hash of the tip commit kind of ensure the consistency of all the commits made before. It makes what we call a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph).

**So, if one data is different, the hashes can't be equal.**

Example of content of a commit blob that you could get using the command `git cat-file -p <HASH_OF_A_COMMIT>` (it's the `parent` line which is important here):

```
tree ed43bc2d5c708478b7ddf3a60a94e66779020b47
parent 50a1cc19b66e10e0d25aecfdc9eaa3685747f0c9
author Me<me@gmail.com> 1687375465 +0200
committer Me<me@gmail.com> 1687898375 +0200

Here is the commit message...
```

Comment: *can't be equal* → are most likely not equal

Comment: One of has `https://github.com/<redacted org>/<redacted repo>.git` and the other has `git@github.com/<redacted org>/<redacted repo>.git`.

Comment: The fact that one URL is using https and the other ssh as transports does not produce a difference.... it should be the same thing coming out of them if it's the same repo you are going against.